# Operator precedence in C (pointer arithmetics)

Tags: c, pointers

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
*p = 1, *(p+1) = 2, *(p+2) = 3, *(p+3) = 4, *(p+4) = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    //what exactly is going on in these lines?
    printf("%d %p\n", (*p++)++, p); 
    //printf("%d %p\n", (*++p)++, p);
    //printf("%d %p\n", ++(*p++), p);
    //printf("%d %p\n", ++(*++p), p);
}
```

What is operator precedence in these lines above?

Comment: In which line? What is unclear to you?

Comment: As there is no sequence point in the arguments passed to `printf` you don't know what value of `p` will be printed.

Comment: `int ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);` : you mean `int * p = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);` I suppose ?

Comment: Pointer arithmetics in printf lines.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings to quickly detect  various problems.

Comment: Look at an [operator precedence chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), factor in [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order), and you should be able to figure it out. If there is something specific you don't get, or are not sure about, *then* ask *just about that*.

Comment: @Sand There is no pointer arithmetic in your code because there are no pointers involved.

Comment: order of evaluation is not the same as operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

If we add parentheses to all potentially ambiguous expressions in the code above, we get:

```
int p = malloc((sizeof (int)) * 5);
(((((*p) = 1), ((*(p+1)) = 2)), ((*(p+2)) = 3)), ((*(p+3)) = 4)), ((*(p+4)) = 5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d %p\n", (*(p++))++, p); 
}
```

That is:

- `sizeof` has higher precedence than `*`
- unary `*` has higher precedence than `=`, `=` has higher precedence than `,`, and `,` is left associative
- postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`

---

There is no pointer arithmetic in your code because there are no pointers. `int p` declares an `int`.

That's why `*p = 1` doesn't even compile, so this code doesn't actually do anything.

If you fix that, the code still doesn't do anything because the `(*p++)++, p` part in your `printf` call has undefined behavior: It's modifying `p` and reading from `p` without an intervening sequence point.

Answer (score 1):

> *p = 1, *(p+1) = 2, *(p+2) = 3, *(p+3) = 4, *(p+4) = 5;

is equivalent to (in that case, not always)

> *p = 1; *(p+1) = 2; *(p+2) = 3; *(p+3) = 4; *(p+4) = 5;

---

concerning

> printf("%d %p\n", (*p++)++, p);

the order of the execution or the arguments is indeterminate, so same for the result

P.S. next you put a code, please check before it is possible to compile it without error  (`int ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);` must be `int * p = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);`)

Answer (score 1):

Let's draw some pictures.  After the first two lines, you have the following:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+
   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+
     ^
     |
     |
     |
   +---+
p: |   |
   +---+
```

The expression `(*p++)++` is parsed as `(*(p++))++` and is evaluated as follows:

```
  p++    - evaluate to the current value of p (&p[0]); as a side effect, 
           update `p` to point to the next object in the sequence (&p[1])
 *p++    - dereference the result of `p++` (p[0])
(*p++)++ - evaluate to the current value of the thing `p` points to 
           (1), then increment the value of that thing.
```

After that expression has been evaluated, our state is now

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+
   | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+
         ^
         |
     +---+
     |
   +---+
p: |   |
   +---+
```

The expression `(*++p)++` is parsed as `(*(++p))++` and evaluates as:

```
  ++p     - evaluate to the current value of p plus 1 (&p[2]), which gives us
            the address of the next object in the sequence; 
            update p to point to the next object (&p[2])
 *++p     - dereference the result of ++p (p[2])
(*++p)++  - evaluate to the current value of thing following what p currently 
            points to (3), and as a side effect increment that thing.
```

After that expression has been evaluated, our state is now

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+
   | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+
             ^
             |
     +-------+
     |
   +---+
p: |   |
   +---+
```

You should be able to work out the other two.  However...

The statement

```
printf("%d %p\n", (*p++)++, p);
```

invokes *undefined behavior*, because you're both trying to read `p` and update it without an intervening sequence point.  The value that gets printed for `p` may or may not reflect the update from `p++` or `++p`.  Function arguments are not guaranteed to be evaluated in any particular order.